# how to translate Google Analytics from marketing-speak to tech-speak?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Back in the dinosaur days, I was the sole Webmaster for my organization (dev, admin, templates, etc) and I monitored usage stats with [Analog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_%28program%29). As we grew larger I focused on more dev stuff, and handed off analysis to other people (TBH I think it often fell by the wayside).

Now our new Director of Communications has asked me to implement more features of Google Analytics. However, I don't grok the jargon. Cohorts? Conversions? Dimension Drilldowns? Could someone translate it into terms for a middle-aged techie slightly on the unix-beard side?

Specifically, what is the GA terminology/tool for:

- tracking of navigation methods & paths (menus, inline links, sidebars, etc)
- non-HTML documents viewed (which would be so easy with an apache log, grr)
- offsite exit links (GA can do this without needing an exit redirect, yes?)

Comment: Ok, is that narrower?

Comment: AFAICT, this question is now on-topic, objective, constructive, and its answer would be moderate in length.
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask